# Can I don't create a file with writeFileStream?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I create a writeFileStream and pipe it with readableStream.

When on data, I check length of data to if length too short, don't create a file with writeFileStream.

Can I abort create a file with writeFileStream, or unlink the file after file created?

Thanks for your help.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { ReadableMock } = require('stream-mock')
const { assert } = require('chai')

describe.only('fs', () => {
  const expectedPath = './file.txt'
  const input = 'abc'
  const reader = new ReadableMock(input)
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(expectedPath)

  before((done) => {
    let index = 0
    reader.pipe(writer)
    reader.on('data', () => {
      index++
      if (index === 1) {
        reader.unpipe(writer)
        done()
      }
    })
  })

  after(() => {
    fs.unlinkSync('./file.txt')
  })

  it('should not create file', () => {
    assert.isFalse(fs.existsSync(expectedPath)) // expected true to be false.
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're trying to achieve I'd create a `PassThrough` stream and use `highWaterMark` to tell me when the stream has been filled - you won't need much code and the streams will give you so little overhead you won't notice (not with writing to disk or reading from HTTP). ;)

Here's what I'd do:

```
  const reader = new ReadableMock(input)
  const checker = new PassThrough({
    highWaterMark: 4096  // or how many bytes you need to gather first
  });

  reader
    .once('pause', () => checker.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(expectedPath)))
    .pipe(checker);
```

What happens here is:

- `reader` is piped to `checker` which is not connected to anything, but has it's highWaterMark level of bytes that it allows (you may add encoding there to use chars instead of bytes)
- `checker` is paused, but on pipe `reader` will unpause and try to write as much as it can
- `checker` will accept some data before returning `false` on write that will emit `pause` event on `reader`
- the listener only now creates the `writer` and it's underlying file and pipes the `checker`
- the `checker` gets unpaused and so gets `reader`

If the number of bytes is lower than `highWaterMark`, `pause` will not be emitted on `reader` and so the file won't get created.

Mind you - you may need to close connections and clean up if this is not a mock, otherwise you may leave those hanging and waiting to be read and soon you'll exhaust incoming connection limits or available memory.

Comment: This is not answer that I wanted, but thanks to new technique that control stream :D.

Comment: Well I don't believe there's another way. The file creation is scheduled as soon as the createWriteStream is called. You write a simple function that would return the checker only and from outside perspective it would look exactly the same as calling createWriteStream.